# Как вывести массив с true/false с помощью библиотеки Graphics. Тетрис JAVA

Tags: java, graphics

Я как и многие начинающие программисты пишу клон Tetris на ЯП Java. И когда дело подошло к остановке падающих фигур. Я остановился на решение с многомерным массивом.
[image: Вот так это выглядит]

Вопрос заключается в том как мне выводить true значения с помощью библиотеки Graphics?

Comment: Не совсем ясен вопрос. Что значит выводить True значения из Graphics?

Comment: Допустим просто закрашивать квадрат там где написано true

Comment: Тебе нужно создать класс сетки игрового поля размером m на n, каждая ячейка этой сетки может быть либо заполнена (true) , или свободна (false).

Comment: Можете написать пример, как это должно выглядеть?

Comment: Часов через 10-12

Comment: Хорошо, буду ждать, спасибо за отзывчивость.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Идем прямо по проектной документации. На схеме мы видим сетку с ячейками, которые могут быть заполнены, или нет. Соответственно, удобно ввести класс который будет за это отвечать. Класс этот должен хранить двумерный массив ячеек и иметь методы изменения их состояния. Пишем (Mesh - сетка с английского):

```
// Файл Mesh.java
import java.util.Vector;

public class Mesh {

    // Vector устаревший тип для коллекций, но для данной задачи подойдет
    private final Vector< Vector<Boolean> > _cells;    

    // Конструктор
    Mesh(int rowCount, int colCount)
    {
        _cells = new Vector<>();
        // Устанавливаем количество строк сетки
        _cells.setSize(rowCount);

        // ДЛя каждой строки создаем столбцы и устанавливаем их количество
        for(int i = 0; i < _cells.size(); i++)
        {
            Vector<Boolean> cols = new Vector<Boolean>();
            cols.setSize(colCount);
            // Заполняем наш вектор значением false, иначе в нем будут null
            Collections.fill(cols, false);
            _cells.set(i, cols);
        }
    }

    public int getRowCount()
    {
        return _cells.size();
    }

    public int getColCount()
    {
        if( _cells.isEmpty() )
            return 0;

        return _cells.get(0).size();
    }

    public void setCellValue(int row, int col, Boolean value)
    {
        if( row > -1 && row < _cells.size() )
        {
            if( col > -1 && col < _cells.get(row).size() )
            {
                _cells.get(row).set(col, value);
            }
        }
    }

    public Boolean getValue(int row, int col)
    {
        if( row > -1 && row < _cells.size() )
        {
            if( col > -1 && col < _cells.get(row).size() )
            {
                return _cells.get(row).get(col);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Следующий этап.**

Конструктор класса `Tetris` наследника JPanel:

```
public Tetris()
{
    // Создаем сетку в 10 строк и 5 столбцов
    mesh = new Mesh(10, 5);

    // Для примера закрашивания ячеек я указываю, что ячейки последнего ряда все true       
    for(int i = 0; i < mesh.getColCount(); i++)
        mesh.setCellValue(9, i, true);
}
```

Метод `paint`, отрисовка сетки и true-ячеек:

```
//...
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    super.paint(g);

    // Ширина и высота одной ячейки
    int cellWidth = getWidth() / mesh.getColCount();
    int cellHeight = getHeight() / mesh.getRowCount();

    int h = 0, w = 0;

    for( int row = 0; row < mesh.getRowCount(); row++ )
    {
        for( int col = 0; col < mesh.getColCount(); col++ )
        {                                                
            if( mesh.getValue(row, col) )
            {
                // Цвет заполненных ячеек красный
                g.setColor(Color.red);
                g.fillRect(w, h, cellWidth, cellHeight);                    
            }

            // Цвет границ ячеек черный                
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawRect(w, h, cellWidth, cellHeight);

            w += cellWidth;                
        }                
        h += cellHeight;
        w = 0;
    }
}
//...
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89438/discussion-on-answer-by-alexander-chernin-----true-false--).